# Leetcode "Decode Ways" problem and recursion error

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to solve the Leetcode Decode Ways problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways/). Consider a string with upper case elements from the English alphabet represented by numbers.
So `A` maps to `1`, `B` maps to `2`, and so on until `Z` maps to `26`. Given a string of numbers, how many ways can one decode it to a string of alphabets?

For example, `11106` can be mapped into:

```
"AAJF" with the grouping (1 1 10 6)
"KJF" with the grouping (11 10 6)
```

Note that the grouping `(1 11 06)` is invalid because `06` cannot be mapped into `F` since `6` is different from `06`.

I run into a maximum recursion depth error in Python, even for very short input strings. My solution is below:

```
def numDecodings(s):

    ## Case of empty string 
    if len(s)== 0:
        return 1

    ## Error cases if a zero is in a weird place
    for idx, i in enumerate(s):
        if idx == 0 and s[idx]=="0":
            return 0
        if idx > 1 and s[idx-1] not in "12" and s[idx]==0:
            return 0

    ## Recursion
    def subProblem(substring):
        if len(substring) == 1:
            res = 1
        else:
            res = subProblem(substring[1:])
            if (len(substring) > 1) and (substring[0] == "1") or (substring[0] == "2" and (substring[1] in "0123456")):
                res += subProblem(substring[2:])
        return res
            
    
    return subProblem(s)
```

What is causing the unbounded recursion?

Comment: We don't know what the "decode ways" problem is. Since questions are expected to be complete and self-contained, please include any relevant information in your question, and not as a link to an external resource

Comment: Please also fix the indentation of your code, since badly indented python code is invalid python code. Use [fenced code blocks](/help/formatting)

Comment: If `substring` is long enough, you'll definitely hit the recursion limit...

Comment: Is the error coming from leetcode, or from running it yourself with input that is at or near the maximum allowed length?

Comment: I've added details about the question and fixed the indentation. @JohnGordon, I get the maximum recursion depth exceeded error for any input string of length greater than 1. The error is coming from me running this on my machine (not Leetcode's interface)

Comment: I tried `numDecodings("1122334455")` and did not get a recursion error.  (The answer I got was clearly wrong, but that's a separate issue...)

Comment: @JohnGordon the input is a string of numbers (sorry if this wasn't clear in the question). But for example, `numDecodings("12")` gives me the error. There are some inputs (longer ones) for which it works though. Agreed that there is a logical issue but I am not able to debug it due to the recursion issue.

Comment: You aren't accounting for the case when substring is empty.  Therefore `subProblem()` endlessly calls itself with an empty string as an argument.

Comment: Oh, thank you! That solved my problem. I can accept as an answer if you could add a line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't accounting for the case when `substring` is empty.

Therefore `subProblem()` endlessly calls itself with an empty string as an argument.